# Including the class name in function call

Tags: c#

I am just learning C# using Microsoft Virtual Academy. Here is the code I am working with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Variables
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myCar = new Car("BWM", "745li", "Blue", 2006);
            printVehicleDetails(myCar);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }  

    abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public abstract string FormatMe();

        public static void printVehicleDetails(Vehicle vehicle)
        {
            Console.Writeline("Here are the vehicle's details: {0}", vehicle.FormatMe());
        }
    }

    class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public Car(string make, string model, string color, int year)
        {
            Make = make;
            Model = model
            Color = color;
            Year = year;
        }

        public override string FormatMe()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
                this.Make,
                this.Model,
                this.Color,
                this.year);
        }
    }
```

Anyway, the problem I am having stems from the line `printVehicleDetails(myCar)`. When I try to build the project, I get the error "The name 'printVehicleDetails' does not exist in the current context.

I can fix the error by changing the line to `Vehicle.printVechicleDetails(myCar)`.

Does anyone know why I have to include `Vehicle` in that line?

Comment: Because it's required by the C# standards? How would the compiler know which method are you referring to?

Comment: You are calling it in a class called `Program`, but the method is a static method in the class `Vehicle`. How do you expect it  to know where to find the method? The real question is why do you have it as a static method instead of an instance method anyway?

Comment: @walther I'm new to C# and all OOP, how was I supposed to know this?

Comment: @MattBurland I am following along with "C# Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners" on MVA. After re-watching the video, it looks like PrintVehicleDetails was supposed to be a function in Program and not in Vehicle.

Comment: @JPetersen: That would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printVehicleDetails` is a static method. To access it, you have to tell it where the method is, which is why changing it to `Vehicle.printVehicleDetails` works.

Alternatively, you could remove `static` from the signature of `printVehicleDetails` and remove the need to pass a vehicle parameter and then call it via `myCar.printVehicleDetails();`.

```
public void printVehicleDetails()
{
    Console.Writeline("Here are the vehicle's details: {0}", this.FormatMe());
}
```

By the way, `printVehicleDetails` doesn't confirm to the generally accepted [C# naming standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx). It should be `PrintVehicleDetails()`.

Answer (score 5):

Because `printVehicleDetails` is a static method *on the `Vehicle` class*.  When you call a static method (on a class other than the one you're in) you need to include the class name so the compiler knows which method to bind to.

Comment: Not 100% sure but i think that is supposed to change with c# 6.0

Comment: @Franck: there will be an option to import static methods (with a variant of the `using` statement) from a class into the global namespace, but it won't just happen automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have `printVehicleDetails` as a static method, which means that it belongs to the class as a whole and not to an instance, such as your `myCar` variable. What you have works as is, but it's not ideal. In the object-oriented world, we want to have methods that operate on objects, rather than global methods (which is essentially what static methods are). That is, instead of having a method that takes a dog and makes it bark, we have a method that is called on the dog so that the dog can bark itself.

In order to fit into that paradigm, I would get rid of `printVehicleDetails` altogether and just use `FormatMe`. It would look like this in your `Main` method:

```
Car myCar = new Car("BWM", "745li", "Blue", 2006);
Console.WriteLine("Here are the vehicle's details: " + myCar.FormatMe());
Console.ReadLine();
```